# setResult works MOST of the time

Tags: android, start-activity, activity-finish

I've worked with setResult(RESULT_OK, intent) for a while now, and am experiencing something strange.

MOST of the time, about 3/4 of the time that I enter an activity then exit from it using the following code which is ALWAYS executed:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();   
intent.putExtra(KEY_ENVIRONMENT_SURVEY, esurvey);       
setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);   
finish();
```

In the activity being returned to, most of the time, RESULT_OK is returned, but sometimes RESULT_CANCELLED is returned, seemingly quite randomly. What could be causing this? Could finish() be called before the esurvey is attached (it's parcelable) and the default is RESULT_CANCELLED? If so how can I fix this? Use a handler and use postDelayed or check to see if RESULT_OK was set (I don't know how to do this, so please specify if that's the solution)?

Thanks!

Comment: "If a child activity fails for any reason (such as crashing), the parent activity will receive a result with the code RESULT_CANCELED."
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

Comment: Yes, but the activity does what it's supposed to (nothing unusual in the logcat from what I've seen) most of the time. I guess I need to investigate further to see if this is the cause.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'm revisiting this because I found the glitch in my application. The "back" button was very close to a button I had designated as moving to the next activity. I was allowing button presses to be registered after the first one, so sometimes the activity would seem to have completed by touching the "done" button, but was actually being navigated back to by the "back" button.

I fixed this using a boolean flag, checking to see if it was true upon a butotn press, and then setting it to true if it equaled false.

Answer (score 0):

Try to move this code into overridden `finish()` method. This will ensure it's called every time activity is finished.

```
@Override
public void finish() {
    Intent intent = new Intent();   
    intent.putExtra(KEY_ENVIRONMENT_SURVEY, esurvey);       
    setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);   
    super.finish();
}
```

Comment: I'll try this. Do you think that anything in those lines of code could cause the activity to crash?

Comment: @TomMcFarlin No. They are safe.